# Creating External Monitoring for a web app

Tags: web-services, web-applications, monitoring, amazon-ec2

The company I work for built and hosts a web app used by our customers and I am interested in creating some kind of external monitoring page (similar to trust.salesforce.com) that users can go to to see the current state of our servers/app. I know there are tons of different 'monitoring' services out there but I want to create the service myself, to have complete control and customization. Obviously, the service would have to be hosted in a different location and data center than the app itself. One thing I am concerned about is that if I just choose a different host in a different location, if that host goes down for any reason (power failure, server failure, or even ISP failure) the monitoring software is down. For this reason, I am thinking of hosting the monitoring app on an amazon EC2 instance. With their elastic IP feature, if for some reason the data center or point where the instance is running fails, I can just create a duplicate instance with the same data (but in a different location) and everything would work fine still.

Does this sound like a feasible plan? For even more security, I was thinking of creating 2 instances in different locations and monitoring from both of them. If one instance fails, the other would still be up. Obviously, one instance has to act as the actual web host for the monitoring page. Is it possible programatically for one instance to switch the elastic IP over to itself if it detects the other instance has failed for any reason?

I know there's a lot of different things involved in this question, I'm just looking for feedback regarding ANY of it...

If you've made it this far, thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a complicated solution for a complicated issue.  I think you are on the right track with using something like Amazon's EC2 to reduce the chance of your monitoring app of going down.  Also, you could develop it yourself but there are a great deal of free monitoring solutions out there like Nagios that will do everything you are asking for and is highly extensible so you can spend your time making it look and feel like you want while leaving the more complicated portions under the hood to software that is tried and tested.  The worst thing would be for you to have a bug in your software that shows something as up when it is actually down.  Based off of what you are talking about doing, I would assume that would be a huge issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an elastic ip - which is only assigned to one instance, consider using the Elastic Load Balancer http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ which then can route over instances in any of the availability zones.  This way AWS manages taking instances in/out of the pool if they become unavailable for some reason and you do not have to spend time 'moving' the Elastic IP around.   It is then easy to assign your monitoring cname to the ELB hostname.

I think RandomBen's idea of using Nagios on your instances is a good one because then you do not have to recreate all the functionality in Nagios.  You then spend development time setting up the system and customizing the look and feel to your needs.

Also, if you can use MySQL, you should consider using RDS http://aws.amazon.com/rds/ although you will need to pay transfer fees if you have servers outside of a region accessing the RDS in another region.